# I am developing app for tracking user activity . i am storing his latlngs every 5sec interval to db and later i want show user his route he travelled

Tags: android, google-maps

I m plotting users pre tracked coordinates on google maps using below code but its drawinf lines from stating point to every platlng point which i am adding to polyline options. i want to plot it properly so that user can see his route he travelled from start to end.

here is code i m trying to do

```
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for(LatLng latLng:mLatlngs.values())
    {
            options.add(latLng);
    }
    mMap.addPolyline(options);
```

[image]

Comment: If you are inside the building, lat-lng will keep fluctuating. You should check the accuracy of location received. If it's around ~10 or less meters then only you should consider it otherwise ignore the location.

Comment: @SandipSoni thanks sandip for info. i corrected my code as u said. i walked around building area u can see the roads around building and i have proper data for same i am just not able to plot it properly.